# AWS IoT core thing subscribe only showing messages from console

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

so here is my code for subbing to the mqtt topic, i am just trying to read the messages.

```
import time
import AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib as AWSIoTPyMQTT

# Define your IoT device credentials
iot_endpoint = ""
iot_port = 8883
device_id = ""


root_ca = r" "
private_key = r""
cert = r""

myMQTTClient = AWSIoTPyMQTT.AWSIoTMQTTClient(device_id)
myMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(iot_endpoint, iot_port)
myMQTTClient.configureCredentials(root_ca, private_key, cert)

# Connect to AWS IoT Core
myMQTTClient.connect()

def printMessage(client, userdata, message):
    print(client)
    print(userdata)
    print(message.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    return True

# Publish CSV data to initial CSV topic
myMQTTClient.subscribe("initial-csv-topic", 0, callback=printMessage)

# time.sleep(4)
# myMQTTClient.unsubscribe("initial-csv-topic")


while True:
    time.sleep(10000)

myAWSIoTMQTTClient.unsubscribe("initial-csv-topic")
```

I successfully see the output on both ends (my laptop and the aws console) when I use the default publish in the console.
[successful output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuIsU.png)

However when i try to publish via a lambda func or through a py file it only shows up on the console. I don't understand why. Here are the docs for the AWSIoTPythonSDK : https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-docs/sphinx/html/index.html
[unsuccessful output - only showing on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIZzF.png)

Comment: Try subscribing and publishing using qos 1. Also, use the aws iot python v2 sdk.